# How to test different media queries for a javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have below `javascript` written, I would like to add tooltip on a button for  every desktop device of different sizes. Can anyone advise how can I mention different media screen in my `javascript` and how could I test it in my laptop for every media screen I included in `style`.

```
        <style>
    .banner-text>div>.banner-link.link-highlight 
    {
        display: none;
    }

    .booking-widget-home 
    {
        background-image: url('https://www.goxyz.in/content/dam/goxyz/6e-website/banner/target/05/Banner-Blue-checks.jpg') !important;
    }

    .banner-title 
    {
        color: white;
    }

    .banner-description 
    {
        color: white;
    }

    .offers-container.offers-up 
    {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .banner-link.link-highlight 
    {

        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .ntooltip 
    {
        position: absolute;
        background: #92dff6;
        color: #3e3158;
        padding: 2px 0;
        border-radius: 10px;
        bottom: 42px;
        left: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 11px;
        width: 130px;
        box-shadow: 2px 5px 14px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    }

    .ntooltip:before

    /* triangle decoration */
       {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-left: 8px solid transparent;
        border-right: 8px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 10px solid #92dff6;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: -10px;
        margin-left: -10px;
    }


</style>
<script>
    (function() 
    {
        'use strict';
        var cnt = 6000;

        function init() 
        {
            if (typeof jQuery != "undefined") 
            {
                // call to change content 
                content_change();
            }
            else 
            {
                cnt = cnt - 500;
                if (cnt > 500) setTimeout(init, 500);
            }
        }


        // function to change your content 
        function content_change() 
        {

            if (jQuery(".booking-widget-home").length > 0) 
            {

                jQuery('.offers-container.offers-up > .offers-wrapper > div >h1 ').text('Kerala Alert!');
                jQuery('.offers-container.offers-up > .offers-wrapper > div > p.banner-description ').html("Tooltip test is successfull</br><span><a href='https://www.goggle.com' target='_blank' class='banner-link link-highlight'>Add snacks</a></span>");

                $('.banner-description > span').append('<div class="ntooltip">Click Here to Know More</div>');

            } 
            else 
            {
                cnt = cnt - 500;
                if (cnt > 500) setTimeout(content_change, 500);
            }
        }
        init();
    })()
</script>
```

Comment: to test in desktop just decrease the size of browser window

Comment: Use the Developer Tools (press F12) in the browser, and you will see the mobile option

Comment: Hi @Roy through the mobile emulator I can check for various mobile devices. Here I want to check for desktop devices with different media screens.

Comment: Use the same tool. It check all screens resolutions